# Realtime data update to the client using Websocket in node js

Tags: node.js, sql-server, websocket, timeout, real-time-updates

I want to send ws message to the client when my sql sever database table values updated or new row inserted (real time data) for that client. how can I achieve this. I'm using **Node js** and **Mssql** for DB. what I tried before was checking every second to DB and sending the records to the clients. But the problem is when more users connected I'm getting database timeout error. Why because I'm checking db for every users every seconds. What can I do now how can I solve this.

Comment: You can try to use events. Here's a package that helps you handling them. https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql-events

Comment: But I'm using Mssql not mysql. In Mssql I don't know there is events available or not till now I'm searching for it.